# phpQuery: редактирование существующего файла без его загрузки в браузере

Tags: php, phpquery

Только начал собирать информацию о библиотеке `phpQuery`, и куда не посмотрю, везде написано "создаём с помощью phpQuery новый HTML-файл". А что, в уже созданные PHP и HTML-файлы внедряться нельзя?

Поясню свою задачу. Я добавляю в свою админ-панель функцию "редатирование заголовка страницы и метаописаний". С помощью jQuery это было бы сделать проще простого, но файл с веб-страницей, который я редактирую через панель, не загружен в браузере; он просто статично лежит в папке. То есто надо открыть файл, заменить метаописания и/или заголовок (`<title>`) без загрузки этого файла в браузере.

Answer (score 0):

Можно. https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/

Используйте
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFilePHP('test.php'); 
Потом делайте что вам надо используя запросы, а потом просто сохраните файл